# "I can wait until when you have time." Does this sound weird?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> "I can wait until when you have time."

I mean I can wait for you, until whenever you have time for me. Is that the right way to say it?

Comment: Is what correct to say? Please [edit] your post to clearly indicate which sentence or sentences you think are incorrect. If possible, please explain why you think they are incorrect.

Comment: @Max: It's quite clear what Serafina is asking. Her English is not as good as yours; that's why she's here. Show a little charity.

Comment: @TonyK I was responding from the review queue. This post was flagged as low quality, so I was hoping to remedy that by having OP post as clearly and as many details as possible. [_Please, everyone… details. Please_](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please.)

Comment: @Max: this question is crystal clear: Is the given sentence correct, or does it sound strange to a native English speaker? No more details are necessary.

Comment: @Max I think pulling the title into the body of the question should make it more clear. Welcome to ELL Serafina - it helps us write better answers if we understand a little more about why you are unsure whether something sounds strange. Is there a particular word or phrase that's bothering you in your sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it sounds weird. Correct is

> I can wait until you have time.

The word *until* plays two roles. It can be a preposition, which takes a noun or a noun phrase:

> Stay at home until Thursday.
>   Wait until the first snows of winter.

Or it can be a conjunction, joining two finite clauses:

> We will fight until we die.
>   I can wait until you have time.

But it can't take an adverbial phrase. So these are wrong:

> I can wait until when you have time.
>   Stay at home until on Thursday.

I hope this is clear! As a bonus, the words *before* and *after* follow the same rules as *until*.